# jQuery text() does not work before a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After an Ajax request, I perform the following.

```
$('#change_ts').text('Defaults Changed!');

//blinking part
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow'), 500);
clearTimeout(t);
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow'), 500);  
clearTimeout(t);
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow'), 500); 
clearTimeout(t);
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow'), 500);  
clearTimeout(t);  
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow'), 500); 
clearTimeout(t);
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow'), 500);  
clearTimeout(t);  
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow'), 500); 
clearTimeout(t);
var t = setTimeout($('#change_ts').text('Change Text/Size'), 500); 
clearTimeout(t);
```

It is my make-shift fade in/out blinker. It works well.

However, the first line has no effect when I perform the blinking part. If I remove the blinking the text of the span is changed. But as soon as I uncomment the blinker, it doesn't change the text at all?!

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks all for any help

**Update**

The set timeout is useless for what I need to do. I have removed it now and I have the following, but I still can not change the text before the fade in/outs?

```
$('#change_ts').text('Defaults Changed!');

$('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow');
$('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow');
$('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow'); 
$('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow');  
$('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow'); 
$('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow');  
$('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow');

$('#change_ts').text('Change Text/Size');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a callback function to `setTimeout`, like this:

```
var t = setTimeout(function() { $('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow') }, 500);
```

Right now, you're calling the fade function immediately and sending the return value to `setTimeout`. You should also change the timeout values to be increasing, like 500, 1000, 1500 etc., otherwise all the fade in/out will occur at the same time. You could use a loop to set-up the values for you. And why are you clearing the timers immediately - they won't have any effect if you do so.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i += 2) {
    setTimeout(function() { $('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow') }, 500 * i);
    setTimeout(function() { $('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow') }, 500 * (i + 1));
}
```

You can also make a generic blinker like this, which will keep blinking until you clear the timer:

```
var state = true;
function blink() {
  state = !state;
  if (state)
    $('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow');
  else
    $('#change_ts').fadeOut('slow');
}

var t = setInterval(blink, 500);
```

This will keep going until you call `clearInterval(t)`.

---

**Update:** The reason the first `text` call has no effect is because the second `text` call is executed immediately and the text is overwritten. Note that the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` return immediately, before the animation is completed, so the second `text` call executes right after that. If you want to wait until the animation is complete, you need to attach a callback to the last fade function, like this:

```
$('#change_ts').fadeIn('slow', function() {
  $('#change_ts').text('Change Text/Size'); 
});
```

Comment: I had it enclosed in quotes at first, but now I tried the above, the text does change, but my fade in/out blinker does not work. It just sets the text?!

Comment: have a look at my updated question. I am not even using any timers but I still can not set the text of the span before I use fade in and out?

Comment: Thank you very much!! I did not realise JQuery's fades worked like that! Once again, thank you very much! I learnt quite a bit especially you correcting in my first attempt with the settimeout. :)

Comment: @Abs: Actually, it's not specific to jQuery. Any animation - in fact, anything that makes use of timed events - runs in the background while the rest of your code is executed immediately.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [jQuery Blink plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blink) instead. You can [see the demo here](http://www.antiyes.com/jquery-blink-plugin) :)

Comment: Yeh, I had a look at this. I thought I could do my own! Failing so far! :)